# I have trouble setting fixed image as background for my body's website

Tags: css, background-image

I want to add a fixed image for my body's background, but it doesn't work yet.

I tried to write the correct code, though even after re-checked it, it doesn't work. I tried to set a background-color, and it's working fine. I also re-checked the image's URL, and it seems to be the good one.

```
body {
  background-image: url:("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/magic-hands-picture-id182751516?k=6&m=182751516&s=612x612&w=0&h=Sh6eYcq8Sbapy1jDwW0bjYO-0295X0Ju8jQbi0YOLAs=");
}
```

No error message. Background remains white & blank. Nothing happened. Here is the

> URL of my Code-pen : https://codepen.io/Peyo5202/pen/zYOrzMZ?editors=0100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove ':' after url

```
background-image: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/magic-hands-picture-id182751516?k=6&m=182751516&s=612x612&w=0&h=Sh6eYcq8Sbapy1jDwW0bjYO-0295X0Ju8jQbi0YOLAs=");
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ':' after the url

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/magic-hands-picture-id182751516?k=6&m=182751516&s=612x612&w=0&h=Sh6eYcq8Sbapy1jDwW0bjYO-0295X0Ju8jQbi0YOLAs=");
}
```

You can also make background image fixed by adding following CSS :

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for background image is as follows :

```
background-image: url("{Image-URL}");
```

In your case you have added extra `:` after `url`, That is the reason it's CSS is getting invalid.

You can simply make following change and get your background image working as expected.

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/magic-hands-picture-id182751516?k=6&m=182751516&s=612x612&w=0&h=Sh6eYcq8Sbapy1jDwW0bjYO-0295X0Ju8jQbi0YOLAs=");
}
```

You can also add background to body from tag directly as follows :

```
<body background="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/magic-hands-picture-id182751516?k=6&m=182751516&s=612x612&w=0&h=Sh6eYcq8Sbapy1jDwW0bjYO-0295X0Ju8jQbi0YOLAs=">
```

For more info on background image property please follow below link :

[CSS background-image Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)